# WCF RIA's HasChanges for EntityFramework

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I'm currently converting some code over from Silverlight/WCF RIA Services to WPF/Entity Framework. The codebase made extensive use of the [HasChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domaincontext.haschanges%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) property of the RIA Domain Context. The view would bind to this property to determine button states. For example, a form would bind to this `HasChanges` property, and whenever the user changed *any* property of *any* entity inside the `DomainContext`, the `HasChanges` would become true and the Save and Discard buttons would become enabled.

After doing some research, it is apparent that EF does not have an equivalent `HasChanges` property on the `ObjectContext`. Does anyone have any clever ideas on how one would go about duplicating this functionality inside of Entity Framework?

I suppose these would be the important features for such a property:

1. This new `HasChanges` property would
   become true whenever any property of
   any entity loaded into the
   `ObjectContext` changes.
2. The `HasChanges` would become false
   whenever the `SaveChanges` method is
   successfully called on the
   `ObjectContext`.
3. The `HasChanges` property throws a
   `PropertyChanged` event which the view
   would catch in order to update
   button states / etc.

Anybody have any ideas? Maybe a custom ADO.NET EntityObject Generator?

Comment: If anybody is interested, Rune has a good idea on how to accomplish this at this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9154e9ca-8a02-4eb1-9707-153132c3f3a1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution isn't quite ideal, but it works. Also note that I'm using Self Tracking Entities within a WPF application.

To check for changes

1. Create an instance of the context
2. ApplyChanges() from the model to the context
3. Check context.HasChanges()

```
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        context.MyTable.ApplyChanges(myTableInstance);
        return context.HasChanges();
    }
```

This works well, even for a graph of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however this solution is lacking the features of the RIA HasChanges in that no event is fired when a property on an entity is changed. In your solution, it appears that you have to 'poll' the context and ask if there are any changes. I guess what I'm after is one event I can subscribe to on the Context that is fired whenever any entity's property is changed in the graph.

Comment: What type of entities are you using? Standard EF entities, POCOs, or Self Tracking? If you're using POCO or Self Tracking, then one option would be to modify the T4 template to raise such an event.